# Creating an object of abstract class URLConnection or HttpURLConnection in Java

Tags: java, object, abstract-class, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I saw the following code in a tutorial:

```
URLConnection connection = new URL("http://example.com").openConnection();
```

How is that possible? The API says that URLConnection (and also the Subclass HttpURLConnection) is an abstract class. But abstract classes cannot be instantiated. I also saw other tutorials with (for example) this code:

```
URL url = new URL( "http://java-tutor.com/index.html" );
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
```

Why is there no 'new'? For me that's very strange, so can someone explain this to me.

Comment: `url.openConnection()` is a method that returns an implementation of `URLConnection`. This implementation is not in the java API, but in the Sun classes. With a debugger you might be able to see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
openConnection();
```

creates an instance of implementation of `URLConnection` class (sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection   @Credit goes to Sotirios).

Based on [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection%28%29):

If for the URL's protocol (such as HTTP or JAR), there exists a public, specialized URLConnection subclass belonging to one of the following packages or one of their subpackages: java.lang, java.io, java.util, java.net, the connection returned will be of that subclass. For example, **for HTTP an HttpURLConnection will be returned**, and for JAR a JarURLConnection will be returned.

Comment: `HttpURLConnection` is also abstract. It goes deeper than that, but I can't find an implementation class.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: You are correct. What I meant there was, some implementation class will be returned which is of type URLConnection, that is why URLConnection ==....openConnection() is valid call.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection`. With an IDE, you would see `Access restriction: The type HttpURLConnection is not accessible due to restriction on required library C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Thanks! Will edit answer with your comment.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't instantiate `URLConnection` but `URL` at:

```
URLConnection connection = new URL("http://example.com").openConnection();
```

`URLConnection` is the variable type (which can be `abstract` or **even an** `interface`), `URL` is the specific class you instantiate.

About the no new word, `openConnection()` returns `URLConnection` object so you don't need to create one yourself.

Comment: Yeah I know that openConnection() returns URLConnection, but URLConnection is abstract and I found this strange.

Answer (score 1):

`URL` is a factory that creates a `URLConnection` based (if memory serves me correctly) by a scheme. You can have `HttpsURLConnection` or `HttpURLConnection`.

Answer (score 1):

URLConnection is indeed an abstract class.  It cannot be instantiated.

So as not to be useless, however, for every abstract class in a class structure there must be a subclass (maybe several levels removed) that is concrete, i.e. that can be instantiated.

URL.openConnection() is returning one of those subclasses to you.  You could verify this with a debugger, if you like.  URLConnection is the type of the reference you call "con," not the type of the object referred to by that reference.